# How can I reuse a View object?

Tags: ios, swift, view

[image: View]

I have that view object with some elements. I want to call that view , and can use it in another view, having a list of objects view one below the other. The problem, I do not know how I can create like a component.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a reusable UIView, so in your case I think you will create a xib in Xcode.

Regards, Jorge.

Comment: Could you explain me how I can create this element?

Comment: When you create a new File, go to "user interface" and later select view. And another option is when you select source, you select cocoa touch class and later select the subclass and click "Also create XIB file".

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of UIView, and do what you need to in the view, and every time you want to use this kind view, just use an instance of this class.

Comment: do you have one web or place where I can see this, because I do not how I can do this ... I am starting now with swift and I would like to reuse this view with the same control have inside

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to `Container view` in interface builder